# How to generate noisy mock time series or signal (in Python)

Tags: python, time-series, signal-processing

Quite often I have to work with a bunch of noisy, somewhat correlated time series. Sometimes I need some mock data to test my code, or to provide some sample data for a question on Stack Overflow. I usually end up either loading some similar dataset from a different project, or just adding a few sine functions and noise and spending some time to tweak it.

What's your approach? How do you generate noisy signals with certain specs? Have I just overlooked some blatantly obvious standard package that does exactly this?

The features I would generally like to get in my mock data:

- Varying noise levels over time
- Some history in the signal (like a random walk?)
- Periodicity in the signal
- Being able to produce another time series with similar (but not exactly the same) features
- Maybe a bunch of weird dips/peaks/plateaus
- Being able to reproduce it (some seed and a few parameters?)

I would like to get a time series similar to the two below [A]:

[image: Real time series 1]
[image: Real time series 2]

I usually end up creating a time series with a bit of code like this:

```
import numpy as np

n = 1000
limit_low = 0
limit_high = 0.48
my_data = np.random.normal(0, 0.5, n) \
          + np.abs(np.random.normal(0, 2, n) \
                   * np.sin(np.linspace(0, 3*np.pi, n)) ) \
          + np.sin(np.linspace(0, 5*np.pi, n))**2 \
          + np.sin(np.linspace(1, 6*np.pi, n))**2

scaling = (limit_high - limit_low) / (max(my_data) - min(my_data))
my_data = my_data * scaling
my_data = my_data + (limit_low - min(my_data))
```

Which results in a time series like this:

[image: Mock time series]

Which is something I can work with, but still not quite what I want. The problem here is mainly that:

1. it doesn't have the history/random walk aspect
2. it's quite a bit of code and tweaking (this is especially a problem if i want to share a sample time series)
3. I need to retweak the values (freq. of sines etc.) to produce another *similar but not exactly the same* time series.

[A]: For those wondering, the time series depicted in the first two images is the traffic intensity at two points along one road over three days (midnight to 6 am is clipped) in cars per second (moving hanning window average over 2 min). Resampled to 1000 points.

Comment: Have you considered taking an ideal data set and just adding some white noise to it?

Comment: A bit yeah, but then I'm still stuck with the problem that all the actual features (weird dips/peaks, periodicity etc.) are still _exactly_ the same

Comment: To change periodicity I guess it would be feasible to resample various parts to slightly more or fewer points.

Comment: Have you ever thought about using biological data? 
Check this out, 
You cold download a large chromosome (eg chr1) or the smallest (chr21) then use a moving average where you calculate the %GC content.  Nothing like biological data for random walks with plateaus, local dip and peaks...

Comment: Do you find a good time series generator? I am also looking for such a library in java or python ... ?

Comment: @user3352632 https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/signal.html#waveforms allows you to make some time series, though I'm sure there's better generators out there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you looked into [TSimulus](https://github.com/cetic/TSimulus)? By using [`Generators`](https://rts-gen.readthedocs.io/en/latest/), you should be able generate data with specific patterns, periodicity, and cycles.

> *The TSimulus project provides tools for specifying the shape of a time series (general patterns, cycles, importance of the added noise, etc.) and for converting this specification into time series values.*

Otherwise, you can try "drawing" the data yourself and exporting those data points using [Time Series Maker](https://github.com/mbonvini/TimeSeriesMaker).